# Looping through nested JSON arrays/objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to loop through a local JSON file using PHP and am struggling to access the correct info. I need to retrieve the coordinates for each country and push these into a new array, with the country name as a key and the coordinates as values.

The JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": { "name": "Bahamas", "iso_a2": "BS", "iso_a3": "BHS", "iso_n3": "044" },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [-77.53466, 23.75975],
                            [-77.78, 23.71],
                            [-78.03405, 24.28615],
                            [-78.40848, 24.57564],
                            [-78.19087, 25.2103],
                            [-77.89, 25.17],
                            [-77.54, 24.34],
                            [-77.53466, 23.75975]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            [-77.82, 26.58],
                            [-78.91, 26.42],
                            [-78.98, 26.79],
                            [-78.51, 26.87],
                            [-77.85, 26.84],
                            [-77.82, 26.58]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            [-77, 26.59],
                            [-77.17255, 25.87918],
                            [-77.35641, 26.00735],
                            [-77.34, 26.53],
                            [-77.78802, 26.92516],
                            [-77.79, 27.04],
                            [-77, 26.59]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
```

I've got the file in PHP using file_get_contents and json_decode, and have tried a foreach loop in PHP to access each nested element, but hit a snag when looping through the json with multiple errors:

```
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Warning: Undefined variable $features
```

How could I access the coordinates, and add them to a new array?

EDIT:

code I'm using is:

```
<?php 

$geoJsonContents = file_get_contents("geoJsonInfo.json");

$geoJsonArray = json_decode($geoJsonContents, true);

//echos -77.53466 23.75975, which is correct
// echo $geoJsonArray['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0][0][0] . " " .
// $geoJsonArray['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0][0][1];

foreach($geoJsonArray->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[0][0][0][0] as $coordinates)
{
    echo $coordinates;
}

?>
```

Comment: trying to loop on the coordinates ?

Comment: Trying to loop through the json, retrieve the name of a country and assign this as the key in a new array, then retrieve the coordinates values, and assign these as the values for the new array. There are 175 countries to loop through in the same format.

Comment: Maybe post your code so we can tell you what eventually went wrong? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, added the code I have which produces the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! The echo was right, but you went from array to object in the foreach

```
foreach($geoJsonArray['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0][0]  as $coordinates)
{
    echo $coordinates."<br/>";
}
```